# Which of the three methods to create Activerecords objects in Rails it the best? And why should one be chosen over the other?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I see that in Rails ActiveRecord objects can be created using three different methods as shown in the link below, which one is the best?

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_basics.html#create

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They all achieve the same result, just in different ways. *There's no "best" way.*

---

You will have different use cases for each, for example, the accepted way of saving an object in a Rails controller is as follows:

```
#app/controllers/your_controller.rb
class YourController < ApplicationController
   def new
      @model = Model.new
   end

   def create
      @model = Model.new model_params
      @model.save
   end
end
```

As mentioned in the other answer, the underpin of this is that you'll always be invoking an instance of your model class. The difference lies in the intricacies of how it works (`create!` saves on the base class):

> **create!(*args, &block)**
>
> Similar to #create, but calls create! on the base class. Raises an exception > if a validation error occurs.
>
> Expects arguments in the same format as Base.create!.

The best example of this is with `destroy` and `delete`:

> **destroy(id) public**
>
> Destroy an object (or multiple objects) that has the given id. The
>   object is instantiated first, therefore all callbacks and filters are
>   fired off before the object is deleted. This method is less efficient
>   than ActiveRecord#delete but allows cleanup methods and other actions
>   to be run.

And for `delete` - no ActiveRecord callbacks are invoked (it's more or less pure SQL):

> **delete(id_or_array) public**
>
> Deletes the row with a primary key matching the id argument, using a
>   SQL DELETE statement, and returns the number of rows deleted. Active
>   Record objects are not instantiated, so the object’s callbacks are not
>   executed, including any :dependent association options.

---

Also, you have to remember that [ActiveRecord has a series of hooks](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html) it calls when saving/updating models:

[image]

So if you use `create`, it's going to call the hooks responsible for this. Very important when deciding which to use.

In the end, it's best to stick to convention until you find fault with it. It's convention because it works well; maybe not the best, but if you're stuck for which method to use, it's probably best to experiment from the baseline of what you know to operate properly.

Answer (score 0):

All those three methods have their different use cases. No one is BEST or better than the other. It depends on the context you are using them.

For example,

> **create** method call will create and save a new record into the database

while:

> Using the **new** method, an object can be instantiated without being
>   saved.

So there are differences among those methods and you will use the one that best suits your context/use case in your application.